# MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find the resource "YYY" among resources embedded in the assembly

Tags: vb.net

You can get around this problem by simply not using the resource file but selecting the file in the file system.

```
'frmJTLWAWI_categroy_readin_GUI.Designer.vb
   btnAbot.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("btnAbbrechen.Image"), Image)
```

This is the error message that appears everywhere

> MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find the resource
> "JTL_Translator.frmMain.resources" among the resources "" embedded in
> the assembly "JTL Wawi Übersetzungssoftware", nor among the resources
> in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the
> resources were embedded with an incorrect name.

Can someone explain to me how I can fix this error?

i've tried a lot resgen.exe and vbc nothing can stop this error, only to disable every resources.GetObject()

now i get the following main error message:

the inner error message is the message i told above

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Application-defined or
> object-defined error."

the startup for the project is broken if i put one image system.drawing in the projekt.I Think the project \My Project\resources.resx or resources.Designer.vb Resources.Designer.resx is broken.
How could i regenerate this file to be Working?

Internalst error message is this one in the autogenerated frmMain.cs but i'm in frmMain.vb (VB.NET)

```
[STAThread]
    'frmMain.cs write protected a file
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(MyProject.Forms.frmMain);
    }
```

if i assign an image over the Visual Studio 2022 GUI i receive the error message at startup.

if i do this:
loading the image @runtime everything works.

```
  Dim img As Image
    img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\gfx\Navigationsmenü\navigationsleiste_artikel.png")
    pMainPictureBox.BackgroundImage = img
```

i added this in my project file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30456?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC30456)

`<VBRuntime>Default</VBRuntime>`

Now it says that Visual Basic is not found.

Error BC30456   "navigationsleiste_artikel" is not a Member of "Resources".

Comment: The comment says frmJTLWAWI_categroy_readin_GUI, the exception says frmMain.  The resource statement assignment says btnAbot, retrieving a resource for btnAbbrechen.  That's quite a mess, unclear how that happened.  Wild guess: do not edit the Designer.vb file yourself.

Comment: You can get around this problem by simply not using the resource file but selecting the file in the file system.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 19.0.0 Preview 1.1 fixed the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2022 19.0.0 Preview 1.1 fixed the Bug with the resources.